# Looking for device to be able to swap monitors connected to different computers

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm

I expect it to be some kind of KVM switch, but not a classical one (two computers — one minitor) for I have a somewhat specific situation.

I have two laptops. Each of them connected to external monitor, i. e.

```
computer A — monitor A
computer B — monitor B.
```

This time and another I would like to have possibility to swap monitors (ideally with a button click), to have it like this:

```
computer A — monitor B
computer B — monitor A.
```

I know that it is possible, in principle, to connect two computers to the same monitor, but those laptops have single HDMI socket each.

The last but not least I found a couple of switches that allow to do just what I need (and set up more complicated configurations) but they cost about 100 dollars which is beyond me at the moment. I need something cheap and dirty (honestly, the task does not sound like something that requires a very sophisticated piece of hardware).

Comment: I dont think that this is a common requirement, so there may only be a few options.  Could you post  a link to what you found